# Could a best-practice question be a good fit for Stack Overflow?

Tags: discussion

I wonder if questions that ask about a best practice in a particular programming area might be a good fit for Stack Overflow? Answers to these questions are very often based on an experience instead of sheer linkable facts but still... they can be very interesting and useful.

For example, I originally wanted to post [db design: circular references for the-one-of-many case](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/219343/db-design-circular-references-for-the-one-of-many-case) on Stack Overflow. In the end, I could imagine the question being closed because I also propose two solutions and ask which is "better". That is why I posted on Programmers. Was it the right choice?

Comment: Relevant: [Are good practices really that opinion based?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/208740/152515)

Comment: Whiteboard questions should indeed be asked on Programmers - it is a better place for them than [so].

Comment: This question appears to be obsolete because the questioner made the right choice in the first place.