# Where to ask good practice questions?

Tags: discussion, questions, off-topic

OK, I got it. There has been plenty of [zombies](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing) asking dumb good practice questions. And yes, most of the good practice questions lead to opinion-based answers.

But then, good practices a essential for learning and mastering programming languages. And good practice question may even be [fine additions to the site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/208740/are-good-practices-really-that-opinion-based).

StackExchange's format is great to gather opinions from experienced users. So if I still have good practice or a opinion-based questions (e.g. I hesitate between two ways of programming/structuring my code and I would like experienced users to argument over one or another), where can I ask them?

Couldn't there be a sub-site of StackExchange dedicated to such kind of questions?

I know my question is pretty opinion-oriented. But Meta is the one place where opinion-oriented questions are asked. Why not somewhere else?

Comment: Already got a down vote :). I thought it was "good practice" to say why in the comments :-p

Comment: On normal sites, it is encouraged but not required to explain a downvote. On Meta sites, like this one, downvoting often means "I disagree with the proposal in this question and I do not want to see it implemented", and no further comment is required. With that said, I will now downvote this question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/08/gorilla-vs-shark/

Comment: I agree with the gorilla vs shark question: it's stupid to ask what is better and it can only lead to flame wars. But when you have an actual technical question, like "what are the advantages of this software design over this other one" or "is this a good way of structuring my code", the answers will indeed be opinion-based but with proper arguments would be positive for the questioner and the community.

Comment: The fact that anyone downvoted this question makes me wonder what the hell is wrong with some folk on here. I found this because I searched Google trying to find the right place to ask  a question such a s "what is the best way to implement....". It really does annoy me so much that Stack Exchange has such a petty minded community. I mean what is wrong with asking a community of "experienced" people the best way/good practice way to do something. That means that other people can then search and find the best way also.

Comment: @Ben what would be the proper channel or site for a question in the scenario you proposed? @ Jamie Lindsey same question brought me here and I couldn't agree more.

Comment: IMHO, it depends the subject of your question. Clearly, Stackoverflow is not the best place. Yes, you might get a good answer despite the downvotes. However, there are topic-specific forums that are probably better. Reddit is the first thing that comes to my mind. Depending on the sub-reddit you are posting to, you have a higher probability to engage in a discussion that might lead somewhere. Too bad it's not here however, as the technical level of answers here is, I think, much better than Reddit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only places on the Stack Exchange network (besides the exception of Meta discussion) where opinion-oriented questions might be OK to ask are in some of its chat rooms.

However, before doing so, be sure that you understand the scope of what can be discussed in a particular chat room.